# Federated Module using Webpack 4.X

Tags: webpack, module, federation

Does Webpack 4.X versions provide Module Federation ? if so, is the implementation different from the way we do it on Webpack 5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Webpack 4 **does not** currently support module federation.

In the [Micro Frontends Slack group](https://micro-frontendsgroup.slack.com), there is mention that the [author of Webpack module federation](https://twitter.com/ScriptedAlchemy) has discussed back porting it to Webpack 4 but I haven't found any evidence to suggest that or mention progress.

**Update:** Here is the [Github issue where he mentions backporting it](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10352#issuecomment-587162038), though he doesn't discuss it after that.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this one: https://github.com/module-federation/webpack-4. For me, it did work fine in "development" mode on a SPA container project created for webpack 4.47.0, it did load other federated modules created with more modern CLI's for webpack 5. The only problem, which is a major show stopper for me, is that I cannot do "production" build, it gives me some webpack plugin issues :'(

**Update**: The "production" build issue can be solved by disabling parallelization of the build process. For me it was "parallel: false" flag in vue.config.js file.

So overall it is the only solution I found that can enable to upgrade step by step a huge legacy project based on webpack 4. Sometimes upgrading webpack 4 to webpack 5 is just simply not feasible.